# How to know which user is owner of a folder in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I have a shared folder in Dropbox, from which I need to remove a user. Since I am not the owner of the shared folder, I cannot do this. However, there are almost fifty members of the folder, and I don't remember who originally created this folder.

[image: Dropbox shared screenshot]

Is there any way I can know which of these fifty users is the owner of this folder?

Answer (score 5):

Dropbox shows you the information in the same dialog box in a light grey shade. I just missed it when browsing a list of 50 users.

[image]